# how to apply in DebuggerHiddenAttribute dependent/cascade methods

Tags: unit-testing, debugging

I'm trying to ignore a exception that happen when run my test Methods.
I`m using a unitTest proyect.

The problem apears when 
TestCleanup Method runs. It's a recursive method. This method clean all entities created in DB during the test. This is a recursive method because of dependences.

Anyway this method call to delete generic method in my ORM(Petapoco). It throws an exception if it can't delete the entity. Any problem, it run again with recursive way until delete it.

Now the problem, if i'm debugging VS stop a lot of times in Execute method because of failed deletes. But I can't modify this method to ignore it. I need a way to ignore this stops when i'm debugging tests. A way like DebuggerHiddenAttribute or similar.

Thanks!

I tried to use DebuggerHiddenAttribute, but cannot works in methods called by main method.

```
[TestCleanup(), DebuggerHidden]
public void CleanData()
{
    ErrorDlt = new Dictionary<Guid, object>();
    foreach (var entity in TestEntity.CreatedEnt)
    {
        try
        {
            CallingTest(entity);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (!ErrorDlt.ContainsKey(entity.Key))
                ErrorDlt.Add(entity.Key, entity.Value);
        }
    }
    if (ErrorDlt.Count > 0)
    {
        TestEntity.CreatedEnt = new Dictionary<Guid, object>();
        ErrorDlt.ForEach(x => TestEntity.CreatedEnt.Add(x.Key, x.Value));
        CleanData();
    }
}

public int Execute(string sql, params object[] args)
{
    try
    {
        OpenSharedConnection();
        try
        {
            using (var cmd = CreateCommand(_sharedConnection, sql, args))
            {
                var retv = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                OnExecutedCommand(cmd);
                return retv;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseSharedConnection();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        OnException(x);
        throw new DatabaseException(x.Message, LastSQL, LastArgs);
    }
}
```

Error messages are not required.